# Exporting an ImageCollection to a CSV in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, ndvi, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am pretty new to using the code editor. I am trying to export ten-day NDVI composites (images from Sentinel-2) to a table (as a CSV file). I think my problem lies with not knowing how to convert my `ImageCollection` to `FeatureCollection` (btw. in this version survey data is simplified).

```
var surveydata = ee.Geometry.Point (16.13298, 77.85595);

// study area
var studyArea = ee.FeatureCollection(surveydata);
var surveyData = ee.FeatureCollection(surveydata); 

// Load Sentinel-2 data.
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2');

// Load cloud masking tool
var s2mask = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:cloud_masks').sentinel2;

// function to apply NDVI calculation to every image in collection
function addNDVI(image) {
  var NDVI = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(NDVI);
}

//set a list of start dates
var startDate = '2020-05-01';
var endDate = '2020-09-30';
var interval = 10;
var increment = 'day';
var tendayDifference = ee.Date(startDate).advance(interval, increment).millis().subtract(ee.Date(startDate).millis());
var listMap = ee.List.sequence(ee.Date(startDate).millis(), ee.Date(endDate).millis(), tendayDifference);

//function to get a tenday composite
function gettendaySentinelComposite(date) {
  // Only include the NDVI
  var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                      .filterBounds(studyArea)
                      .filterDate(date, date.advance(interval, increment))
                      .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 60)
                      .map(s2mask())
                      .map(addNDVI)
                      .select('NDVI');
  var composite = s2.max()
                      .set('system:time_start', date.millis(), 'dateYMD', date.format('YYYY-MM-dd'), 'numbImages', s2.size());
  return composite;
}

var ndvi_tenday = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(listMap.map(function(dateMillis){
  var date = ee.Date(dateMillis);
  return gettendaySentinelComposite(date);
}));

print(ndvi_tenday);

var tempTimeSeries = ui.Chart.image.series({
      imageCollection: ndvi_tenday,
      region: studyArea,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
      scale: 100,
      xProperty: 'system:time_start'
    })
    .setChartType('ScatterChart')
    .setOptions({
    title: 'NDVI-over-time',
    vAxis: {
      title: 'NDVI'
    },
    lineWidth: 1,
    pointSize: 4,
    series: {
      0: {color: 'blue'},
      1: {color: 'red'},
      2: {color: 'green'}
    }
});

print(tempTimeSeries);

// Convert the object to an image with one band for each tenday period
var ndvi_tenday = ee.ImageCollection(ndvi_tenday)
.toBands();

// code to plot one band (one tenday period)
var image = ndvi_tenday.select("9_NDVI");

Map.centerObject(studyArea, 9);
var ndviParams = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};
Map.addLayer(image, ndviParams, 'NDVI image');

print(ndvi_tenday);
```

I thought to use this code for exporting:

```
// Export the image to your google drive
Export.table.toDrive({
        collection: ndvi_tenday,
        description: 'NDVI', 
        folder: 'EE',
    fileNamePrefix: 'NDVI', 
    fileFormat: 'CSV'
    });
```

Here is the link for my code for clarification:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?noload=1&scriptPath=users%2Fanjadamlisby%2FTest%3AS2_NDVI_GPS_Table

Comment: Hi, Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange! In order for you to get the best help, it would be great if you could familiarize yourself with how to write a good post. Please take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and take a look at [this post](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/asking-good-questions-for-gis-stack-exchange). I would suggest replacing the screenshots with code blocks in the text, and resharing your link, because it does not work on my side.

Answer (score 1):

I might have found a solution now. This seems to do it:

```
// Get Zonal Statistics
var reduced = ndvi_tenday.reduceRegions({
  collection: surveyData,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 100,
});

print(reduced);


// the resulting mean is a FeatureCollection
// so you can export it as a table
Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: reduced, 
    description: 'NDVIpolygons', 
    folder: 'EE', 
    fileNamePrefix: 'NDVIpolygons', 
    fileFormat: 'CSV'
})
```